# Bibliography style elsarticle-num-names with DOI and hyperlinks but no explicit url

Tags: hyperref, elsarticle, doi

I prepared my article with **elsarticle**, using **\citep** & **\citet** throughout. I originally used **apalike** bibliographystyle but now need to change it to **elsarticle-num-names** for citation formatting requirements (see point #2 below).

Now, I am attempting to make 2 changes:

1. add DOIs to the bibliography
2. change reference style to `[1]` for **\citep** and `Author et al. [1]` for **\citet**.

I want to keep **hyperref** and do not want explicit URLs (only DOIs) but cannot make this work!

Thank you for any help you might have!

MWE:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
%\usepackage{hyperref}

\journal{Test Journal}
\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\title{The Title}
\author{Prof. Big Ol' Wanker}
\address{123 Happy Lane}
\begin{abstract}
TEXT
\end{abstract}
\begin{keyword}
keyword 1 \sep keyword 2 \sep keyword 3
\end{keyword}
\end{frontmatter}

\section{SECTION1TEST}
\noindent cite: \cite{Richards1931} \\
citep: \citep{Richards1931} \\
citet: \citet{Richards1931} \\

\bibliography{library}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num-names}

\end{document}
```

Here is the reference for Richards1931 from my library.bib file:

```
@article{Richards1931,
author = {Richards, LA},
doi = {10.1063/1.1745010},
file = {:D$\backslash$:/Papers/Richards - 1931 - Capillary Conduction of Liquids Through Porous Mediums - Journal of Applied Physics.pdf:pdf},
issn = {01486349},
journal = {Journal of Applied Physics},
pages = {318},
title = {{Capillary Conduction of Liquids Through Porous Mediums}},
url = {http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/journal/jap/1/5/10.1063/1.1745010},
volume = {1},
year = {1931}
}
```

**without hyperref (wanted hyperlinks present, DOI displays correctly, but unwanted URL is present):**

[image: without hyperref]

**with hyperref (hyperlinks not present, DOI displays incorrectly, and unwanted URL is present):**

[image: with hyperref]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The write-up of your document setup is a bit confusing: The code says you use the `elsarticle-num-names` bibliography style, but in the body of the posting you say you use the `apalike` style. Please clarify. Separately, it would be helpful if you posted the bib code for the entry `Richards1931` to void spurious duplication of effort by readers who may be considering coming up with a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. I have clarified the first sentence and added the Richards1931 entry. My bibtex file is generated automatically from my Mendeley database.

Comment: Not tested but you can either remoave manually all url entries in your bib file or create you own `myelsarticle-num-names.bst` file [from http://www.math.pitt.edu/~troy/stewart/elsevierversion/elsarticle-num-names.bst] and remove all the `print.url output` lines. I think it would work. Otherwise, you could use `biblatex` but the targeted style might not be available.

Comment: @pluton Thanks, this kind of works if I make a new .bst file with those edits... strangely, when I use the doi package instead of the hyperref package, the doi links now work, but the doi is displayed as: **doi:doi:10.1063/1.1745010** Any idea how to get rid of that second **doi:** ?

Comment: I am not sure why you are facing so many difficulties. If this is for a paper, why don't you leave the effort to the editor?

Comment: Good point! I was just getting frustrated with making it look perfect pre-submission.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This problem occurs because `elsarticle` [does not define a `\doi` macro](https://www.tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2012-August/032152.html) that `hyperref` requires.

`Hyperref` calls `\doi{\bibinfo{doi}{XXX}}` to produce the URL for the DOI in the reference XXX. If the `\doi` macro is not defined, the resulting output will be something like `\let\@tempa\bibinfo@X@doi{XXX}`

As a workaround, you can define a `\doi` macro that solve the problem

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\providecommand{\doi}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \let\bibinfo\@secondoftwo
    \urlstyle{rm}%
    \href{http://dx.doi.org/#1}{%
      doi:\discretionary{}{}{}%
      \nolinkurl{#1}%
    }%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
```