# doi package inserting http:/dx.doi.org/\let... instead of http:/dx.doi.org/... in bibliography hyperlinks

Tags: hyperref, citing, doi

When I use the doi package, the links in my bibliography are:

http://dx.doi.org/%5Clet%20...

instead of

http://dx.doi.org/...

Any ideas?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{doi}
\begin{document}
\section{SECTION1TEST}
Equation~\ref{eqn:1}.\\
\begin{equation}\label{eqn:1}
a=b\times c
\end{equation}
\noindent cite: \cite{Richards1931} \\
citep: \citep{Richards1931} \\
citet: \citet{Richards1931} \\
\bibliography{../../Bibtex/library}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num-names}
\end{document}
```

The example entry in my .bib file...

```
@article{Richards1931,
author = {Richards, LA},
doi = {10.1063/1.1745010},
file = {:D$\backslash$:/Papers/Richards - 1931 - Capillary Conduction of Liquids Through Porous Mediums - Journal of Applied Physics.pdf:pdf},
issn = {01486349},
journal = {Journal of Applied Physics},
pages = {318},
title = {{Capillary Conduction of Liquids Through Porous Mediums}},
url = {http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/journal/jap/1/5/10.1063/1.1745010},
volume = {1},
year = {1931}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Could you please provide an example or, even better, an MWE so we can test your code?

Comment: Hi Phillipp. This question stemmed from me attempting to use the doi package to solve my overall problem with a document. It occurs when I add \usepackage{doi} to the example here...   http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258758/bibliography-style-elsarticle-num-names-with-doi-and-hyperlinks-but-no-explicit

Comment: Hmmm, with **hyperref** and my modified **elsarticle-num-names-nourl.bst** file this now works! Seems a bit inelegant, but I suppose it looks like I want it to for the most part... and Elsevier can deal with the details if it gets accepted.

Comment: @tomatessechees so what do you want to do with this question?  Did you find a resolution that you can post as a solution or should it be closed instead?