# How to add doi to elsarticle-num style bibliography

Tags: elsarticle, doi

I'm using `elsarticle` documentclass and would like to add doi to bibliography.

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}

\begin{document}

Palm oil is mainly composed of triglycerides \cite{Mba2015}.

\section*{References}
\bibliography{SFC}

\end{document}
```

Reference example

```
@article{Mba2015,
title = "Palm oil: Processing, characterization and utilization in the food industry – A review",
author = "Ogan I. Mba and Marie-Josée Dumont and Michael Ngadi",
journal = "Food Bioscience",
year = "2015",
volume = "10",
pages = "26--41",
doi = "https://doi.org/10.1016/j.fbio.2015.01.003",
}
```

Comment: Did you saw question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258758/bibliography-style-elsarticle-num-names-with-doi-and-hyperlinks-but-no-explicit Duplicate?

Comment: I hadn't seen this question. Thank @Mensch